# Sitecore.Context.Database.SelectSingleItem("/page-help") not working in CM

Tags: sitecore-api

I have a code that query an alias item like this `Sitecore.Context.Database.SelectSingleItem("/page-help")` but I get an error saying

> End of string expected at position 42.

it only throws this error in my content management but not in my content delivery. How can I fix this in my content management?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape the `-` dashes.

`Sitecore.Context.Database.SelectSingleItem("/page#-#help")` alternatively `Sitecore.Context.Database.SelectSingleItem("/#page-help#")`

References:

- https://blog.istern.dk/2014/10/29/escaping-dashes-in-sitecore-queries-datasource-query-update/
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36991247/can-i-programmatically-escape-dashes-in-sitecore-queries-using-fullpath
- https://blog.nikkipunjabi.com/2016/11/sitecore-query-with-hypen-or-dashes.html

For simple queries like this however, the following would be eaiser

`Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("page-help")`